# In a multi web server farm, how does session state work?

Tags: asp.net, session-state

CASE 1: StateServer

```
<system.web>
   <sessionState     mode="StateServer"     stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42626"     sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes"     cookieless="false"     timeout="20"   />
 ... 
</system.web>
```

CASE 2: SQL Server

```
<sessionState   mode="SQLServer"   stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42626"   sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes"   cookieless="false"   timeout="20" />
```

Question:
1.  In case 1 and 2 appropriate location of sql or state server have to be configured in web.config for each of the web server in farm.

2. Can we have some servers configured as state and some as sql?
3. Can we have some cookieless and some as withcookie
4. Suppose if we use only `<sessionState cookieless="true" />`, then by default which of the modes is used? Can this be done in a multiserver farm, or is it necessary to specify the IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) Can we have some servers configured as state and some as sql?

No, you should not. Suppose when a user makes a request, then one of the server from your Web Farm will store the session in a StateServer. now in case the same user makes another request ( by clicking some links etc...), then image what will happen if your load balancer send this request to the 2nd  Web server ? There will be NO session for the same user as you configured SqlServer mode for the same and the session for the user was stored on a state server on First request.

2.) Can we have some cookieless and some as withcookie ?

Again NO, for a very similar understanding as pointed above. One of the server will use cookies to track the session and the other one Cookieless ( hence URI ) to track the same session and thus, if the request gets forwarded to different servers, NO session will be detected.

3.) Suppose if we use only `<sessionState cookieless="true" />`, then by default which of the modes is used? Can this be done in a multiserver farm, or is it necessary to specify the IP?

Understand that this setting: `cookieless="true|false"`, is just used to *TRACK* the session for a Particular user between the Client side and server side.

The Actual session *DATA* is there stored on SqlServer/State Server, which is defined in your mode settings as:

```
<sessionState  mode="StateServer|SqlServer" ... />
```

if you don't specify any `mode` setting, default value of `InProc` is used.

---

**Additional Note:**
The Cookie or the URI have a `SessionID` associated with them. `SessionID` is a unique string, used to TRACK individual visitor between visits to website.

As a result of `cookieless="true"`, `SessionID` will be embedded in all page URLs. The drawback is that you'll end up with ugly URLs, which are not so good for SEO (search engine optimization) and visitor definitely will not remember it. Here is an example URL of website which uses ASP.NET cookieless sessions:

http://samplewebsite.com/(**45f8c4zyybphaw2mt3dfgnjk4j**)/Home.aspx

Bolded part represents session id, which is used to recognize a visitor.

Comment: Is it necessary to have all servers in farm enable the session state service via services.msc or it is sufficient that only one server in farm has this enabled?

Comment: if you use stateserver mode, then this stateserver is NOT one of your web servers but is an Additional Third server with lots of memory. Both of your web servers ( which host the Website )  will point to this third server.

So, you can guess now that it is on this 3rd server you need to turn services on

Comment: Can we treat one of the webservers as state server. Should be possible right? Agree not good practice. But incase of limited resource

Comment: Yes, you can definitely have one of your webserver as State Server, and in that case make sure ASP.NET state service is running on that particular webserver. No need to start the service on 2nd Web server.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague. If you're hosting one app across multiple servers I would recommend sticking to one method. What if one user first connects to a server with one `mode`, and the next request is handled by another one? The session state would not be accessible/known to the other server.

As to your questions, the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is really quite clear.

`cookieless` does not affect `mode`. If you don't specify `mode`, the default is `InProc`. If `cookieless` is `true`, ASP will use the query string.

Comment: So Inproc, stateserver and sql. all these 3 methods support cookie and cookie less . right?

Comment: Yes. If you don't specify `cookieless`, ASP.NET will use cookie if the user agent supports it, otherwise it will use the query string. They work irrespective of `sessionState mode`.